# Custom Map markar /pin for Map component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, google-maps-markers

How can I create the below image map markar/pin, specially the bottom design that looks like union shape with CSS and in vue js.
Have tried but not getting the same look as in the image below.
Any help from you much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, need to do some math for 100% you can play with it

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 0;
  
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.box-5,
.box-6,
.box-7{
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 5;
}

.box-2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box-3{
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  
  z-index: 3;
}

.box-4{
  position: absolute;
  width:55px;
  height: 25px;
  top:140px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:6;
  
}

.box-5{
  width:22px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: bisque;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 143px;
  left:33px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-left: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  
}

.box-6{
  width:22px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: bisque;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 143px;
  right:33px;;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-right: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;

}
.box-7{
  width:21.6px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  z-index:8;
  top:170px;
}

.box-8{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
  <div class="box-5"></div>
  <div class="box-6"></div>
  <div class="box-7"></div>
  <div class="box-8">
    <p>HELLO</p>
  </div>
```

EDIT

Try this

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 0;
  
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.box-5,
.box-6,
.box-7{
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 5;
}

.box-1 p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.box-2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box-3{
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  
  z-index: 3;
}

.box-4{
  position: absolute;
  width:55px;
  height: 25px;
  top:140px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:6;
  
}

.box-5{
  width:22px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: bisque;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 143px;
  left:33px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-left: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  
}

.box-6{
  width:22px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: bisque;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 143px;
  right:33px;;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-right: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;

}
.box-7{
  width:21.6px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  z-index:8;
  top:170px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box-1">
        <p>HELLO</p>
      </div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
  <div class="box-5"></div>
  <div class="box-6"></div>
  <div class="box-7"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks UPinar, I will check this out and try to play around with it to fix the rest.

Comment: Hi UPinar, I tried the above example and its doesnot work properly for me, The text 'Hello' is moved somewhere else and its doesnot behave as in your example. 
I was wondering why you gave 'position: relative ' to the last 'box-8', Isn't the parent should always be relative and children as absolute ?

Comment: @Ayesha for using z-index, you need to use relative or absolute. You can add text inside 'box-1' too

Comment: Check the edit please @Ayesha

Comment: Hi @UPinar, have tried to play around the values for CSS styles, but still cannot make it look good with the bottom part of the Pin, please see the edit code below.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.box-1,
.box-2,
.box-3,
.box-4,
.box-5,
.box-6,
.box-7 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 5;
}

.box-1 p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box-3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.box-4 {
  position: absolute;
  /* width: 55px; */
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 140px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 6;
}

.box-5 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 22px;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 147px;
  left: 28px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-left: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
}


.box-6 {
  width: 18px;
  height: 22px;
  /* background-color: bisque; */
  z-index: 7;
  top: 147px;
  right: 18px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-top: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
  border-right: 5.5px solid #c8cbd0;
}

/* bottom line*/
.box-7 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #c8cbd0;
  z-index: 8;
  top: 164px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button class="">
  <div class="box-1">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
  <div class="box-4"></div>
  <div class="box-5"></div>
  <div class="box-6"></div>
  <div class="box-7"></div>

</button>
  </div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Hi again UPinar, yes by adding in the box-1 worked fine. I understand that we need index-z for positioning as you wrote earlier but in the code I don't see where you have added postion: relative, its only position absolute.  Secondly I tried to fix the bottom portion but it's seem to be very rough and not smooth looking. I don't know How to fix that, Would be glad to get some ideas from you.

Comment: Please Check the edit please @UPinar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).